# Why do servers not wait for http headers if the http version is not specified in a GET request?

Tags: http, http-headers, netcat

If I make a GET request via netcat without specifying the http version - `GET /`, I get a response from the server without it waiting for me to send any headers and a blank line first. But if the version is there - `GET / HTTP/0.1`, it behaves normally, even if it's `0.1`. I tested it on `google.com`, `apache.org` and `microsoft.com`. Is it defined by the protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This form of request (`GET /` without a version) was used by an early version of the HTTP protocol, known as HTTP/0.9, which did not support headers at all.  See [The Original HTTP as defined in 1991](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html).

Later specs for HTTP 1.0 ([RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945)) and HTTP 1.1 ([RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)) require HTTP 1.0+ implementations to recognize HTTP 0.9 requests and responses ([RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) for HTTP 1.1 later dropped that requirement).

RFC 1945 states:

> The version of an HTTP message is indicated by an HTTP-Version field in the first line of the message. **If the protocol version is not specified, the recipient must assume that the message is in the simple HTTP/0.9 format.**